# How to check for hidden files & folders on NTFS partition using python on linux?

Tags: python, linux, filesystems, ntfs

I am using `NTFS` partition on `linux` machine. I want to identify hidden files and folders on my `NTFS` partition on `linux` using `python`.

How can I achieve this using `python`. Any code snippet / links would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you got so far? Can you identify non-hidden files?

Comment: @Johnsyweb: I just have the code to identify the hidden files on linux platform.. i.e. all files / folders starting with "." (dot character). My requirement is to detect the hidden files and folders on a USB harddisk which has NTFS partition and get connected to my linux machine..

Comment: Do you mean files with the "hidden" attribute? Or some sort of special files not shown by `os.walk`?

Comment: @AndiDog: Yes, I mean files with "hidden" attribute. I have problem with detecting hidden files & folders of Windows files which are accessed by connecting the USB hard disk having NTFS partition to my linux machine.. Hope it clarifies the doubt..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you are using ntfs-3g to mount your NTFS partitions on linux (this is default on most current linux distributions).

You will need to read file extended attributes (see [attr(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/attr)), you can use [pyxattr](http://pyxattr.sourceforge.net/) for this. NTFS attributes are stored in `system.ntfs_attrib` extended attribute as a set of flags which values are documented in [ntfs-3g documentation](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-advanced/extended-attributes/).

Here is a sample code to read and decode NTFS file system attributes and use them to filter files:

```
import os, struct, xattr

# values from http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-advanced/extended-attributes/
attributes = ['readonly', 'hidden', 'system', 'unknown',
              'unknown', 'archive', 'unknown', 'unknown',
              'temp', 'unknown', 'unknown', 'compressed_dir',
              'offline', 'not_content_indexed' ] + ['unknown']*18

def ntfs_attr(path):
    attr = struct.unpack("i", xattr.get(path, "system.ntfs_attrib"))[0]
    for shift, attribute in enumerate(attributes):
        if (attr >> shift) & 1 == 1:
            yield attribute

def main():
    import sys
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print "Usage: %s path attribute" % sys.argv[0]
        a = set(attributes)
        a.remove('unknown')
        print "where attribute is one of:", ' '.join(a)
        sys.exit(1)

    path = sys.argv[1]
    attribute = sys.argv[2]
    print "Files with %s attribute in %s:" % (attribute, path)
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
        if attribute in ntfs_attr(fullname):
            print fullname


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no python interface for NTFS attributes under linux.

[NTFS-3G](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-download/) supports [NTFS file attributes](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-advanced/extended-attributes/) and exposes them for the linux tools `getfattr` and `setfattr` to read and set.

You can use python's [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) to invoke `getfattr` and then parse the output.

Note: on my ubuntu system i had to install the package `attr` to get the commands `getfattr` and `setfattr`.

Comment: just want to ask you before testing as to 'winsys' will work on linux machine?

Comment: @mahendraliya: The WinSys package wraps around the windows API, so it certainly can't be used under linux. I rewrote my answer.

Comment: Why bother with external commands (slow for large number of calls!) if there is a python module for reading extended attributes? Your answer also contains a factual error: ntfs file attributes are supported by ntfs-3g almost from the very beginning (as `system.ntfs_attrib` attribute). What is available only in ntfs-3g-2011.1.15 or later is `system.ntfs_attrib_be` attribute, which is just an endianness-fixed version of `system.ntfs_attrib`.

Comment: @abbot: I agree that is better to use the python module. I did not know that there is one. I do not agree that there is a factual error in my post. The attribute `system.ntfs_attrib_be` is for the commands `getfattr` and `setfattr`, and that is exactly what I wrote in my answer.

Comment: You can also use system.ntfs_attrib with getfattr/setfattr without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is not limited to Python, you can try my example implemented in shell script.

This is also based on `system.ntfs_attrib_be` attribute in NTFS-3G. If you are just going to *use* it and don't care about how it is implemented (in Python or shell), just download it, install `getfattr` and `setfattr` from your distro, and use it.

https://gist.github.com/Explorer09/ac4bf6838c271a9968b3